# ImageView ObjectAnimator transition + collision detection during transition

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview, objectanimator

I have a "track" that goes for 50 "lenghts" and I have imageView that changes position on click for 5 "lenghts" at a time. That transition I handle with animation like this:

```
  anima = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(bar, "translationX", position*pix);
  anima.setDuration(500);
  anima.start();
```

At the end of the track I have another imageview that I want to detect collision with so I after animation I do this:

```
anima.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                if (Rect.intersects(n1, barRect)) {
                   //Stuff after collision
                }


}
```

**My question is**, is there a way to detect collision **during** this animation so I stop it if collision is somewhere between those "5 lenght jumps"

Comment: You need on `AnimatorUpdateListener`. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener.html

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski Thanks for suggestion it sounds promising but I see onAnimationUpdate is method from ValueAnimator and this object doesnt have my ofFloat translation method. Correct me if I'm wrong please

Comment: I see there is a method (for objectAnimator) called addUpdateListener which accepts ValueAnimator so your answer works, I'll just give it a try. :)

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski This works so I you want to submit that as your answer I'll be happy to accept it :) tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @NikolaDespotski I've managed to solve the problem by implementig onUpdateListener for my ObjectAnimator object like this:

```
 anima.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                   //Do collision detection here
            }

  });
```